# Performance Limitation with using multiple C# Task

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm developing a kind of image streaming application via Unity.

This is how it works.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1yIIg.png)

1. Get 1000+ local file list. Each file contains compressed 4K JPEG Image.
2. Sort file list by order and convert to ConcurrentQueue (Thread Safe Queue).
3. Call Task.Run() multiple time. Each Task is looped until all files are converted.
4. Wait initial delay (about 10s) for "buffer"
5. Call Update each frame and change texture of RawImage.

This is simplified code.

```
void Awake() // called once when app start
{
    taskList = new List<Task>();
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfTasks; i++)
        taskList.Add(Task.Run(()=>Work()));
}

void Work()
{
    while (FileQueue.TryDequeue(out var item))
    {
        item.Process();    // run pipeline
        ImageQueue.Enqueue(item);
    }
}
 
void Update() // called each frame
{
    if (ImageQueue.TryDequeue(out var item))
    {
        MyTexture.LoadRawTextureData(item.data)
        MyTexture.Apply();
    }
}
```

For now, I could achieve 15~20 FPS and the goal is 30 FPS.
Before optimizing, I have to write a report on this.

Here is table & chart for this.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MML4x.png)

As you can see, there is a bottleneck in which the performance reached limitation as the number of task increases.
(Test machine is Mac OS with 6-core Intel Core i7)

Regardless improper performance of pipeline3 function, as the number of tasks increases, the time required for all pipeline function increases too.

At first, I thought the problem was the number of CPU core, but tests in 24-core environment show similar graphs.

I was asked for a "technical explanation" for this.
I answered about "Parallel Slowdown" abstractly, but It wasn't be enough and I wasn't a good student, so I'm in trouble.

Please let me know If there are any related articles, manuals, guides, or even keywords about this so I can investigate on.

Thanks for your time.

//-------------------------------------------------------------

### Update (03 / 14)

As @FranzGleichmann advised, I'm benchmarking each components.

The following is the first result of Pipeline1 (Read binary file and decompress)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LEyLm.png)

Pipeline 1 is a simple dll call step and there is little room for optimization, but it seems that there is still an overhead. After discussing it with a fellow developer, as @freakish advised, I decided to split existing ConcurrentQueue for each thread first. There is no doubt that ConcurrentQueue is inefficient as the thread increases. Also, I decided to try using Raw Thread instead of Task. I also considered using Parallel, but I gave up because I needed a kind of thread ID during the pipeline and I was not used to handling Threadpool.

This is updated code (simplified)

```
void Awake() // called once when app start
{
    threadList = new List<Thread>();
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfTasks; i++)
    {
        Thread thread = new Thread(()=>Work());
        thread.Start();
        threadList.Add(thread);
    }
}

void Work()
{
    int ID = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadID;
    while (ThreadQueue[ID].TryDequeue(out var item))
    {
        item.Process(ID);    // run pipeline
        ImageQueue.Enqueue(item);
    }
}
 
void Update() // called each frame
{
    if (ImageQueue.TryDequeue(out var item))
    {
        MyTexture.LoadRawTextureData(item.data)
        MyTexture.Apply();
    }
}
```

Each processing file is about 1~3mb. I think it's light enough to avoid IO limit.

Also, I looked at asset @sharimken recommended. I haven't purchase it yet because of remaining several step(kinda report), but I just changed image processing dll to LibJPEG-turbo and it got better. (I was using FreeImage)

Now I'm waiting for the next turn to profile because 24-core-PC is doing other job. I'll update it again asap, Thanks again for your time and advise.

Comment: i recommend benchmarking the single _components_ of your software to find the bottleneck. my guess would be IO, since multiple parallel operations on a _single_ storage device makes it slower, not faster.

Comment: To expand on what @FranzGleichmann says; what *might* help is if you're able to split the IO work from the processing work, so that you can be doing CPU work (processing) separately and in parallel to the IO work (file loading). This isn't always possible, though, especially for large files. Your actual IO strategy may also be relevant - and depending on the OSes being targeted, it might be that MMF or equivalent may help; otherwise, suitable buffer sizes, parsers (SIMD maybe), etc. But we have almost zero context, so.... :shrug:

Comment: beside IO limit, you also have jpeg decoder limit. There is an existing Unity C# Live Stream solution FMETP STREAM, which you may check it out(1080P 60fps real time capture and stream). https://youtu.be/NKZNuVSSmms

Comment: Thanks for quick advices! I'll gonna investigate them asap my work finish!

Comment: It is quite clear from your description, but Tasks shouldn’t be used to do parallel processing as having too many thread-based tasks can slow down everything. Use the Parallel class for parallel processing of CPU-bound work instead.

Comment: The way you use `Task.Run` is quite inefficient. You basically use three queues at the moment: FileQueue, ImageQueue and the internal queue for tasks. Perhaps you can try running `Work()` in raw threads (as many as cpu cores) instead?

Comment: Or you could just use a Data processing library, such as TPL.DataFlow or Rx.Net or Akka.Net.

Comment: or treat the files as an MJPEG stream...